# Missing a local variable in Soot's Jimple representation

Tags: soot

It seems that there is some internal optimization in soot to reuse local variables while transforming java byte code to Jimple. Therefore, in the Jimple representation, a local variable may be replaced by another local variable. 
Now I want to disable the replacement and preserve all local variables in the source code, but how to do it?

For example, there are three local variables `scanner`, `x`, and `y` in the following method.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (scanner.nextBoolean()) {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(x * x);
        } else {
            int y = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(y * y);
        }
    }
}
```

But in Jimple representation, the local variable `y` is missing. All the definition and usage of `y` is replaced by the local variable `x`.

```
//Jimple represenation with `-w -keep-line-number -p jb use-original-names:true`
    public static void main(java.lang.String[])
    {
        java.lang.String[] args;
        java.util.Scanner scanner, $stack3;
        java.io.InputStream $stack4;
        boolean $stack5;
        int $stack7, $stack10, x;
        java.io.PrintStream $stack8, $stack11;

        args := @parameter0: java.lang.String[];

        $stack3 = new java.util.Scanner;

        $stack4 = <java.lang.System: java.io.InputStream in>;

        specialinvoke $stack3.<java.util.Scanner: void <init>(java.io.InputStream)>($stack4);

        scanner = $stack3;

        $stack5 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: boolean nextBoolean()>();

        if $stack5 == 0 goto label1;

        x = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: int nextInt()>();

        $stack11 = <java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>;

        $stack10 = x * x;

        virtualinvoke $stack11.<java.io.PrintStream: void println(int)>($stack10);

        goto label2;

     label1:
        x = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: int nextInt()>();

        $stack8 = <java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>;

        $stack7 = x * x;

        virtualinvoke $stack8.<java.io.PrintStream: void println(int)>($stack7);

     label2:
        return;
    }
```

I have read the [Soot command-line options](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/master/soot/soot-master/3.0.0/options/soot_options.htm) and tried to disable some functions during Jimple Body Creation. Some options (e.g., `jb.ulp`, `jb.a`) can certainly influence the local variable in Jimple,
but none of them solve the missing local variable `y` problem.

```
//Jimple represenation with `-w -keep-line-number -p jb use-original-names:true -p jb.ulp enabled:false`
    public static void main(java.lang.String[])
    {
        java.lang.String[] args;
        java.util.Scanner scanner, $stack3;
        java.io.InputStream $stack4;
        boolean $stack5;
        int $stack7, $stack10, x#1, x#2;
        java.io.PrintStream $stack8, $stack11;

        args := @parameter0: java.lang.String[];

        $stack3 = new java.util.Scanner;

        $stack4 = <java.lang.System: java.io.InputStream in>;

        specialinvoke $stack3.<java.util.Scanner: void <init>(java.io.InputStream)>($stack4);

        scanner = $stack3;

        $stack5 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: boolean nextBoolean()>();

        if $stack5 == 0 goto label1;

        x#1 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: int nextInt()>();

        $stack11 = <java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>;

        $stack10 = x#1 * x#1;

        virtualinvoke $stack11.<java.io.PrintStream: void println(int)>($stack10);

        goto label2;

     label1:
        x#2 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: int nextInt()>();

        $stack8 = <java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>;

        $stack7 = x#2 * x#2;

        virtualinvoke $stack8.<java.io.PrintStream: void println(int)>($stack7);

     label2:
        return;
    }

======================
//Jimple represenation with `-w -keep-line-number -p jb use-original-names:true -p jb.a enabled:false`
        public static void main(java.lang.String[])
    {
        java.lang.String[] args;
        java.util.Scanner scanner, $stack3;
        java.io.InputStream $stack4;
        boolean $stack5;
        int $stack6, $stack7, $stack9, $stack10, x;
        java.io.PrintStream $stack8, $stack11;

        args := @parameter0: java.lang.String[];

        $stack3 = new java.util.Scanner;

        $stack4 = <java.lang.System: java.io.InputStream in>;

        specialinvoke $stack3.<java.util.Scanner: void <init>(java.io.InputStream)>($stack4);

        scanner = $stack3;

        $stack5 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: boolean nextBoolean()>();

        if $stack5 == 0 goto label1;

        $stack9 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: int nextInt()>();

        x = $stack9;

        $stack11 = <java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>;

        $stack10 = x * x;

        virtualinvoke $stack11.<java.io.PrintStream: void println(int)>($stack10);

        goto label2;

     label1:
        $stack6 = virtualinvoke scanner.<java.util.Scanner: int nextInt()>();

        x = $stack6;

        $stack8 = <java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>;

        $stack7 = x * x;

        virtualinvoke $stack8.<java.io.PrintStream: void println(int)>($stack7);

     label2:
        return;
    }
```

I also tried following parameters: 
`-p jb.cp-ule enabled:false`, `-p jb.dae enabled:false`, `-p jb.cp enabled:false`, `-p jb.lns enabled:false`,  `-p jb.ule enabled:false`, `-p jb preserve-source-annotations:true`
but they does not influence the defined local variables in Jimple.

Any suggestion for disabling the replacement and preserving all local variables in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still interested in an answer to this question. We've found that Soot always optimizes the code while creating a Jimple body, regardless of the related command-line options. We have a fix for that in a specific fork (https://github.com/spgroup/soot), branch `release-3.3.1`.

Running soot with the option `-p jb optimize:false` solves this issue.